# Does a rubber pipe bears more weight when the pressure of water inside it is high?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, fluid-statics

I have passed a rubber pipe across a road to my home temporarily. The pressure of water inside the pipe is very high, the vehicles and school buses passes over it! **i am interested to know that "In which case the pipe can bear more weight/load without rupturing.  Case A: when there is no water inside the pipe,
Case B: when there is a flow of water inside pipe at high pressure?**

Comment: What are your thoughts on this so far?

Comment: didn't ruptured up until now!

Comment: i got no answer till now! is it not a good question?

Comment: The answer to this question is not obvious, although it can be quantified using stress analysis.